# How do I write a comparator that compares 2 different fields in a collection of objects?

Tags: java, scala, object, comparator

My compare function below generates an exception `Comparison method violates its general contract IllegalArgumentException`. Where and what contract is it failing?

```
def compare(self: A, that: A): Int = {

  val xComp = self.x.compareTo(that.x)
   if (xComp == 0) {
    val yzComp = self.y.compareTo(that.z)
     if ( yzComp <= 0) {
      -1 
    } else {
      1 
    }
  } else {
    xComp
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Scala, but in plain Java I'd use something like `Comparator<A> comp = Comparator.comparing(a -> a.x).thenComparing(a -> a.y); comp.compare(this, that)`

Comment: But I want to compare `self.x` to `that.x` but if they are equal, I want to compare `self.y` to `that.z`.
The second set of fields are different fields within the same object.

Comment: Oh, missed that bit.

Comment: Read the contract of a Comparator, your implementation does not respect it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to make a valid comparator with that constraint, even setting aside that you're not returning 0 when `self.y == that.z`.

Most notably, `Comparator` is required to impose a total order, which in particular means that if `compare(a, b) < 0`, then `compare(b, a) > 0`.  This is trivially false for your comparator, if `a` is `(0, 1, 0)` and `b` is `(0, 0, 1)`.

You *cannot* have a `Comparator` that compares `self.y` to `that.z` that works in general for things like sorting and `TreeSet`.